# CORS with Spring Security (v3.2.0)

Tags: spring, security, cors

I'm trying to build and service in between resources with Spring Security and Spring Boot.
My map is following: LandingPage (VM1) -> API Service (SpringApp) -> Resource service with Data (VM_N)
I'm facing the CORS issue in the browser while API calls over POSTMAN works fine.
I know that POSTMAN doesn't care about CORS and therefore the issue is only in the browsers.
Here is my security config on the SA (Spring Application):

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("securityFilterChain ");
        http
                .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
//                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), CorsFilter.class)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
//                .cors((cors) -> cors
//                        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers()
                        .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/info/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oAuth -> oAuth.jwt(jwt -> {
                    jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder());
                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter);
                }))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource());
        return corsFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        LOGGER.info("CORS config load");

        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern(landing); // Landing VM
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, " +
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
        configuration.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        CorsConfiguration publicEndpointConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        publicEndpointConfig.addAllowedOriginPattern(landing); // Landing VM
        publicEndpointConfig.addAllowedOriginPattern(gateway); // Gateway VM
        publicEndpointConfig.addAllowedOriginPattern(php); // PHP VM
        publicEndpointConfig.addAllowedHeader("Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        publicEndpointConfig.addAllowedMethod("HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/info/**", publicEndpointConfig);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/register/**", publicEndpointConfig);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have commented out addFilterBefore and cors() as they seems make no difference to the application at all.

My Controller is following:

```html
    @RequestMapping(value = "**", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = landing)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleOptions() {
        LOGGER.info("INFO handle general OPTIONS requests");

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", landing );
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body("handle OPTIONS requests");
    }

 @RequestMapping(value = "**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = landing)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getAnythingElse(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOGGER.info("user with no authority or role, getAnythingElse");
        String tokenValue = null;
        String phpUri = null;

        LOGGER.debug("Authentication is: " + authentication);
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication;
            Jwt jwt = jwtAuthenticationToken.getToken();
            tokenValue = jwt.getTokenValue();
            LOGGER.debug("Token is: " + tokenValue);
        }

        String requestUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        LOGGER.info("Request: " + requestUrl);

        String regexPattern = ".com/(.*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(requestUrl);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            phpUri = matcher.group(1);
        }

        // Create HttpHeaders and add the token to the request header
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", landing );
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenValue);

        // Create an HttpEntity with the headers
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        // Create a RestTemplate
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        LOGGER.info("Full URL: " + (phpApiUrl + phpUri));

        // Make the HTTP request to the PHP API using exchange method
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                phpApiUrl + phpUri,  // PHP API URL
                HttpMethod.GET,  // HTTP method
                entity,  // HttpEntity with headers
                String.class  // Response type
        );

        // Get and return the response body
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(response.getBody());
    }
```

However, with all this config I still getting errors:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://springApp/login/user_info • (Reason:
> CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null). Blockquote
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://springApp/issue_tracker/? format=json.
> (Reason: header 'cache-control' is not allowed according to header
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight response).
>
> (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://springApplication/storage/count.
> (Reason: expected "true" in CORS header
> "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials").

Based on the Spring documentation this config should be more than enough to work, but it clearly doesn't work.

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with this configuration or point me out where I miss something?

Thanks

UPDATE:

latest update of the code leads to the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https: //springApp/user_info. (Reason: CORS
> preflight response did not succeed). Status code: 403.

Security config now looks like this:

```html
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers(header -> header.addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", landing)));
        http
                .headers(header -> header.addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")));

        http
                .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/info/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oAuth -> oAuth.jwt(jwt -> {
                    jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder());
                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter);
                }))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                ;

        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: `configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");` and "Reason: header '**cache-control**' is not allowed according to header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'". Do you see the error now?

Comment: Also, it is really weird that your _server_ explicitly allows the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" to be received. This header is intended to be sent to and to be processed by the _client_.

Comment: Hi @knittl, removing that header removes one error, but the rest remains the same especially with (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: I have a strong feeling that whatever I do in corsConfigurationSource() make no difference.
I have added this line to http.build .headers(header -> header.addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", landing)))
and now it asks to have Allow-Credentials to be true. So I see difference in changing http.build, but not in the corsConfigurationSource().

Answer (score 0):

You can change `configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern(landing);` to `configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*"); //will accept request from all origins` or you can specify list if origins/domains like `List<String> domains = Arrays.asList("https://localhost:8080", "https://google.com")`

Comment: I have tried before and, unfortunately, it makes no difference.